# Set custom tool property in powershell script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I have a NuGet package, in which I have a powershell script that automatically executes everytime the package is installed. In the package, a .resx file is added. In the powershell script I want to set the custom tool property of the .resx file to `ResXFileCodeGenerator`, so that a designer file is automatically being created. How can I implement this the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here? 
Can you please give us more information about your scenario?

Is your package targeting packages.config world or package reference/project json stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got it working.

Apparently, I just needed the projectitem of the resource file and then set a property like this:

```
$projectItemImages.Properties.Item("CustomTool").Value = $customToolSetting;
```

$projectItemImages is the projectItem object of the .resx file

$customToolSetting is the value I want to set it to, namely `ResXFileCodeGenerator`.

After that, I just had to run the custom tool like this:

```
$projectItemImages.Object.RunCustomTool();
```